# How Visual Studio Code will use to format PHP like PhpStorm?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstorm

I have used `phpfmt` extension to indent the code which formatted code like this

```php
'cms' => [
    'class' => 'yii2mod\cms\Module',
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'defaultRoute' => 'cms',
],
```

And when I merge it return the code intend error. I need the code to format like PhpStorm did this

```php
'cms'   => [
    'class'               => 'yii2mod\cms\Module',
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'defaultRoute'        => 'cms',
],
```

Which extension and how I use it in Visual Studio Code to get rid of PHP intended error in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: what settings are you using for `phpfmt` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam not added any setting, contain default settings

Comment: try using these [settings](https://pastebin.com/PezqjNM6) and check if that is how you want it. will add the answer later if it works.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The site can not be reached when click on setting

Comment: there might be some issue at your end i can see the link is opening ,  turn off any vpn f you are using

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Worked bro please answer it

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following settings that i use for my development env, would be closest to what you are looking for.

Add the following into your `settings.json` in VSCode.

```json
{
  "phpfmt.php_bin": "php",
  "phpfmt.passes": [
        "AlignPHPCode",
        "AlignTypeHint",
        "AlignDoubleArrow",
        "AddMissingParentheses",
        "ConvertOpenTagWithEcho",
        "DocBlockToComment",
        "IndentTernaryConditions",
        "JoinToImplode",
        "PSR2KeywordsLowerCase",
        "PSR2LnAfterNamespace",
        "PSR2CurlyOpenNextLine",
        "PSR2ModifierVisibilityStaticOrder",
        "PSR2SingleEmptyLineAndStripClosingTag",
        "ReindentSwitchBlocks",
        "RemoveUseLeadingSlash",
        "StripExtraCommaInArray",
        "SpaceBetweenMethods",
    ],
    "phpfmt.exclude": [
        "ReindentComments",
        "StripNewlineWithinClassBody"
    ],
    "phpfmt.psr2": false
}
```

Comment: @MuhmmadOmerAslam Some one make it mins 2... haha

Answer (score 0):

For double array formatting you will find in settings like the attached image.
[image]

And if you want to do it in settings.json, add AlignPHPCode into phpfmt.passes array.
[image]